# Android Broadcast receiver doesn't work

Tags: android

I can not seem to figure out why my broadcast receiver does not work. I am looking to receive incoming text messages.

I dont declare the broadcast receiver in the manifest. I register them programatically.

```
    public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
    filter.setPriority(999);
    this.registerReceiver(smsListener, filter);
```

My broadcast receiver is a defined in the activity as such

```
public BroadcastReceiver smsListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
            System.out.println("In broadcast receiver");
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        System.out.println("SMS Message from: " + msg_from);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error when receiving a message");
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Any thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your activity running when you are supposed to receive the message?

Comment: Did you add the RECEIVE_SMS permission also?

Comment: Yes the activity is running. Shouldnt it work in the background as well? I do have RECEIVE_SMS permission in the manifest.

Comment: Nope if you want to work in background you should register your receiver in a Service! This receiver will only work when this Activity is on foreground!

Comment: A Service is not necessary to get the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast. However, if you want to handle that broadcast even when the Activity is not running, you do need register the Receiver class in the manifest.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there any way to control that broadcast (i.e turn it on and off) if you register it in your manifest?

Comment: You cannot stop the sender from broadcasting, but within `onReceive()` you can choose whether to act upon receipt. Also, it is possible to disable the Receiver component completely with `PackageManager`.